# In my header I have the token but it is saying no token as if there is no token. but when it try it on postman it works fine. what is the problem here

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, react-redux, mern

this is my action code:

```
    export const accept = (clinicianId, duration) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .post(
      "http://localhost:5000/api/patient/authAccess",
      clinicianId,
      duration,
      tokenConfig(getState)
    )
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: ACCESS,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(
        returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, "ACCESS_FAIL")
      );
    });
};
```

this is how I set the token and also add it to my header:

```
export const tokenConfig = getState => {
const token = getState().auth.token;


const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
};


if (token) {
  config.headers["x-auth-token"] = token;
}

return config;
};
```

and this is my api where the token will go to the auth function and authorize the user:

```
  const { clinicianId, duration } = req.body;
  jwt.sign(
    { id: clinicianId },
    config.get("jwtSecretAccess"),
    { expiresIn: duration },
    (err, token) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json({
        token
      });
    }
  );
```

when I checked the value of the token there is one i think the api can't read it? I don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Axios interceptor as you can add a header for each http request

https://dev.to/teroauralinna/global-http-request-and-response-handling-with-the-axios-interceptor-30ae